# SQL Server unique periods of absence

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please take a look at the following task?

I have a table `DATA` with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE DATA
(
    EMPLOYEE nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ABSENCE_START nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ABSENCE_END nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

It contains the following data:

```
insert into DATA (EMPLOYEE, ABSENCE_START, ABSENCE_END) 
values ('emp01','21/06/2017','22/06/2017'),
       ('emp01','24/06/2017','27/06/2017'),
       ('emp02','22/06/2017','24/06/2017'),
       ('emp02','22/06/2017','27/06/2017')
```

As you can see for 'emp02' employee we have two periods of absence and one of them (row 4) **completely contains** another period of absence (row 3).

I need to merge these two rows to one (row 4).

Expected result would be:

```
EMPLOYEE   ABSENCE_START    ABSENSE
---------------------------------------
emp01      21/06/2017       22/06/2017
emp02      24/06/2017       27/06/2017
emp01      22/06/2017       27/06/2017
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you made any attempt to to solve your problem?

Comment: I tried to use MAX and MIN aggregation functions for this. But this also merge data for 'emp01' employee.

Comment: You should **always** store dates as datatype `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` - **NOT** as `nvarchar` !!

Comment: I know it, but customer provides above table in that way.

Answer (score 0):

If the only overlap correction you are looking for is when one row completely contains another, and you have no unique row identifier, you can use `not exists()` like so:

```
set dateformat dmy;
;with cte as (
  select 
      employee
    , absence_start= convert(date,absence_start)
    , absence_end  = convert(date,absence_end)
  from data
)    
select *
from cte d
where not exists (
    select 1
    from cte i
    where i.employee=d.employee 
      and i.absence_start <= d.absence_start
      and i.absence_end >= d.absence_end
      and (i.absence_start <> d.absence_start 
         or i.absence_end <> d.absence_end)
    )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PHF88226

returns:

```
+----------+---------------+-------------+
| employee | absence_start | absence_end |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
| emp01    | 2017-06-21    | 2017-06-22  |
| emp01    | 2017-06-24    | 2017-06-27  |
| emp02    | 2017-06-22    | 2017-06-27  |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Did you notice that the dates are typed nvarchar?

Comment: It produces the following result:
emp01 21/06/2017 22/06/2017
emp01 24/06/2017 27/06/2017
emp02 22/06/2017 24/06/2017

Comment: Thank you, SqlZim!

Comment: Have a nice day!

Comment: i don't think this produces the correct result for emp02. The end date should be `2017-06-27`.

Comment: @vkp You're right, I flipped my arrows. Corrected now

Answer (score 0):

The query should look like this:

```
select
*
from dbo.DATA t1
where not exists (
            select
            *
            from dbo.DATA t2
            where t1.ABSENCE_START >= t2.ABSENCE_START
                and t1.ABSENCE_END < t2.ABSENCE_END)
```

But what if you have overlapping absences. Like this:

```
insert into DATA(EMPLOYEE,ABSENCE_START,ABSENCE_END) values
('emp01','21/06/2017','22/06/2017'),
('emp01','24/06/2017','27/06/2017'),
('emp02','22/06/2017','29/06/2017'),
('emp02','22/06/2017','27/06/2017')
```

Comment: Thank you, Dean! If you mean partially overlapping, e.g.
emp02  '22/06/2017'   '25/06/2017'
emp02  '21/06/2017'   '24/06/2017'

Comment: @DavidFreeman, yes that is what I mean. What result do you expect in that case?